# PowerShell HelpNotFoundException: could not find forfiles in a help file in this session

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am using PowerShell version 5.1, build 15063, revision 138.

When I try to access the manual page for the `forfiles` command using `help`, I get an error that looks like this:

[image]

I have tried running `Update-Help` as administrator. I also tried running it with the options recommended by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39834452/powershell-fails-with-update), but still PowerShell finds nothing.

I know I can access the documentation for `forfiles` [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551(v=ws.11).aspx), but that sort of defeats the purpose of the `help` command. I'm also worried there is some deeper configuration issue with my machine or OS that is causing this and that it will cause other problems down the line.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`forfiles.exe` is an *external utility* - a binary executable unrelated to PowerShell - so it is *not* covered by PowerShell's help system.**

You can invoke `forfile.exe`'s command-line help as follows:

```
forfiles /?
```

In order **to determine what type of command a given name refers to, use the [`Get-Command`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command) cmdlet**:

```
> Get-Command forfiles

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source                                                                           
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------                                                                           
Application     forfiles.exe                                       10.0.14... C:\WINDOWS\system32\forfiles.exe
```

As you can see, the `.CommandType` property of the object returned by `Get-Command` indicates the command's type.

Use the `-All` switch if there's a chance that a given name can refer to *multiple* commands - the one that will take effect when referenced by name only will be listed first.

---

As for **what kinds of commands / topics PowerShell's [`Get-Help`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help) command *does* cover**:

- Alias
- Cmdlet
- Provider
- General
- FAQ
- Glossary
- HelpFile - these are the *conceptual* help topics whose names match `about_*`
- ScriptCommand
- Function
- Filter
- ExternalScript
- All
- DefaultHelp
- Workflow
- DscResource
- Class
- Configuration

Note: These are the values that the `Get-Help` cmdlet's `-Category` parameter accepts, as reflected in `Get-Helps` syntax diagram, as shown by `Get-Help -?`,

Not all categories will have actual topics associated with them, but you can query a given category with
`Get-Help -Category <categoryName>`