# Is anybody having this Powershell "Update-Help" command, issue?

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.0

I am trying to download and install Help files for all the commands but it won't work. I am using Powershell 7.1.1 inside the Windows Terminal.

```
Update-Help: Failed to update Help for the module(s) 'ConfigDefender, PSReadline' with UI culture(s) {en-US} : One or more errors occurred. (Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (The specified blob does not exist.).).
```

English-US help content is available and can be installed using: Update-Help -UICulture en-US.

This is exactly what the out-put looks like

[image]

Comment: Nope, `Update-Help` works fine on my Raspberry with Powershell 7.1.1. Did you try the suggestion: `Update-Help -UICulture en-US`?

Comment: [1] i vaguely recall reading that the help for PSReadLine is _case sensitive_ ... and they changed the case of the module name. [*sigh ...*] lookee ... >>> Updating help for the PSReadLine module | PowerShell — https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/updating-help-for-the-psreadline-module/ <<< ///// [2] some modules simply don't have working update functions ... some don't have any at all. your other module[s] may be such.

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate. This just solved one of the problems. I have one more module. The "ConfigDefender" module.  Look : "Update-Help: Failed to update Help for the module(s) 'ConfigDefender' with UI culture(s) {en-US}"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell fails with Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39834452/powershell-fails-with-update)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solved, thanks to another post I've found on stackoverflow.
[According to this Microsoft Forum](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/updateing-powershell-user-help-files/07afd880-c543-4e56-9446-1e9eb509003d), the below command should bypass any errors and give you a successful run of cmdlet `Update-Help`

```
 Update-Help -Verbose -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Comment: There's no indication Nathan works at MS, @robinhood. Personally, I'd run it as `Update-Help -UICulture en-US -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`. Probably doesn't solve the issue--neither does Nathan's suggestion!--but at least, it doesn't spit out as much garbage.

Comment: Yours would work as well. Well, either way. And I don't know of which Nathan are you taking about? :smile

Comment: The one signing the highlihgted answer there, @robinhood 

Comment: The issue wasn't if he works or not at MS.
The command above solved the issue I had. That's all I wanted to show here.

Comment: Ok. So the _fix_ was to hide the errors underneath the carpet (`-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`)? lol

Comment: The Windows way @sotn,  and it works actually!! :)

Comment: "According to Microsoft" is misleading. This guy is not a representative of Microsoft but just a user answering on a Microsoft's site.
Furthermore, this command line doesn't fix anything. It just don't display the errors (AKA "safely ignore").

Answer (score 10):

The issue is the capitalization of PSReadline, which changed to PSReadLine with PowerShell 6.

Fix is easy:

1. Close all PowerShell windows
2. From TaskMgr make sure to kill any remaining PowerShell processes.
3. Open Admin Cmd prompt (not PowerShell) and run the following:

```
ren "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PSReadline" PSReadLine
ren "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadline" PSReadLine
```

That's it. Now you can close the Cmd prompt window, open a PowerShell window and do a normal Update-Help.

See this blog for some additional context:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/updating-help-for-the-psreadline-module-in-windows-powershell-5-1/

Comment: Wow! That's the stuff, and not a single upvote. Have mine ;)